# kubernetes error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for extensions/, Kind=Deployment

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, kubectl

Integrated kubernetes with jenkins and run the command in Jenkins file `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml --validate=false` and getting the error:

```
unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for extensions/,Kind=Deployment
```

But if I run the same command in terminal I am able to deploy my image. deployment.yaml file is given below

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: appname
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: appname
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: appname
        image: appname
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: Are you sure that deployment.yaml exists when you fire that command from within Jenkins? Also validate=false is a bad practice

Comment: If your version is 1.9.0+ try apps/v1

Comment: removed --validate=flag now getting an new error                         Error from server (Forbidden): <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:
  
Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read

Comment: I am also getting the error: `error: unable to recognize "https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml": no matches for apps/, Kind=Deployment`

Comment: fixed by passing kubeconfig file in jenkins as enviroinmental variables and gave the permission to the folder /etc/kubernetes.

Comment: @Dhinesh Could you elaborate on how to get the kubeconfig file, im using gke. Also im not seeing any /etc/kubernetes folder on my jenkins server, should i create it?

Answer (score 10):

I suppose your minikube (if you are checking in your local machine) is NOT running.
Start minikube using the following command

- $minikube start

Now try

- $kubectl create  OR
- $kubectl apply